# How to render Max(Substring) with Lambda Extensions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria, nhlambdaextensions

I'm using NHibernate with Lambda Extensions. I'd like to know how to nest a Max function with a Substring.

The following statement retrieves `Max("invoice_id")`

```
var ret = session
          .CreateCriteria<Invoice>()
          .SetProjection(Projections.Max("invoice_id"))
          .UniqueResult();
```

but in my case the field invoice_id is made in this way: 12345.10 where 12345 is the invoice number, and 10 refers to the current year (2010). Moreover every year the invoice number re-starts from 1.
So I need to calculate the Max function only over the first 5 digits. How can I do it?

Comment: Does it matter? Won't the max be the same regardless? (i.e. 12345#### vs 12346####, the latter is still the max regardless of what 4 digit year is on the end)

Comment: Yes of course, but every year the invoice number re-starts from 1.
Sorry I forgot to specify it before..

Comment: makes much more sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a server-specific function like SUBSTRING (or its equivalent in your DBMS) like so:

```
var ret = session
.CreateCriteria<Invoice>()
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.Max(
            new SqlFunctionProjection("SUBSTRING", 
                NHibernateUtil.String, 
                Projections.Property("invoice_id"), 
                Projections.Constant(1), 
                Projections.Constant(5))))
    .UniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a struct and custom NHibernate type for the invoice number rather than relying on string manipulation.

The struct and nh type will encapsulate all the logic for comparing and sorting.

http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx